# How to clear/reset a fetch with SSR Next 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm wondering how I can recall the `validateToken` fetch if somewhere down below (nested in `Navigation` for example) a user signs out. What is a good way to clear the `user` variable (or set a user to it)?

Layout.tsx:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const response = await validateToken(cookies());
  let user = null;
  if (response.success) user = response.data;

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Navigation user={user}
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

When I refresh the page the `user` data is always up to date so server-side it is working.

Full code can be found here:
https://github.com/lextoc/tracky-next

Comment: store a token inside the cookie or store user inside in localStorage.

Comment: @KannuMandora This is not possible because there is no localStorage server-side. Implementing this would break and give me an error on server-side render. Please feel free to provide a working example because I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: I'm also not going to store every single global piece of information in a cookie... Hopefully there is another solution.

Comment: put a single state in cookie like `authenticated: true or false`; then check each time before you set that in Navigation user

Comment: @MdMinhazAhamed If I'm signed out and then sign in, than this functionality does not fetch the user. Can you provide an example if I understood you wrong.

Comment: When you sign out, are you updating that cookie to false and vice-versa?

Comment: @MdMinhazAhamed Yes, I've also provided the import for the cookies that I use, that's the only way to get them on the server-side to my knowledge.

Comment: I've posted the issue on Next's Github discussion as well: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/53050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue (was simpler than I thought ) with React Query's `initialData`. I've still got an issue where the data is not always displayed but that's going to be something client-side React Query related. For those interested here you can find the solution:
https://github.com/lextoc/tracky-next/blob/main/app/layout.tsx#L67

Comment: Actually still not SSR but this is the best it gets I believe